# JULIA Plots GR savefig error

Tags: plot, julia

When I run Plots in JULIA using JUNO for the first time **savefig(Path)** gives me the following error. The error disappears when I run the long simulations for the second time. Any clues why this happens?

**CODE**

```
Characteristic curve
            gr()
            Plot1= plot(Se, 10.*log10.(H_vg), label= "Vangenuchten")
            plot!(Se, 10.*log10.(H_kg), label= "Kosugi")
            plot!( title= "THETA(h)", xlabel= "Se [-]", ylabel= "log10 h [cm]", linewidth=4)


            # Unsaturated curve
            Plot2= plot(Se, Kr_vg, label= "Vangenuchten")
            plot!(Se, Kr_kg, label= "Kosugi")
            plot!(title= "K(theta)", xlabel= "Se [-]", ylabel= "Kr [-]", linewidth=4)

            #Infiltration
            Infiltration_Inv2= Infiltration_Inv[i_Sample, 1: Infiltration_N[i_Sample]]
            Infiltration2= Infiltration[i_Sample, 1: Infiltration_N[i_Sample]]
            Infiltration_Hydro2 = Infiltration_Hydro[i_Sample, 1: Infiltration_N[i_Sample]]
            T2=  T[i_Sample, 1:Infiltration_N[i_Sample]]
            Plot3= plot(T2, Infiltration2, label= "Observed")
            plot!(T2, Infiltration_Hydro2, label= "Best")
            plot!(T2, Infiltration_Inv2, label= "Simulated")
            plot!(title= "INFILTRATION METHODS", xlabel= "Time [minutes]", ylabel= "Infiltration [mm/minute]", linewidth=4)

            #DθDh
            Plot4= plot(Se, DθDh_kg)
            plot!(title= "Pore Size Distribution", xlabel= "Se", ylabel= "Probality Distribution", linewidth=4)

            plot(Plot1, Plot2, Plot3, Plot4, layout=(4,1))
            savefig(Path)
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
**LoadError: MethodError: no method matching setcharheight(::Float64)**
*The applicable method may be too new: running in world age 22349, while current world is 22350.*
Closest candidates are:
  setcharheight(::Real) at C:\JULIA\pkgs-0.6.2.1\v0.6\GR\src\GR.jl:1071 (method too new to be called from this world context.)
while loading C:\JOE\Main\MODELS\SOIL\BEST\MAIN_BEST.jl, in expression starting on line 260
#gr_set_font#463(::Symbol, ::Symbol, ::ColorTypes.RGBA{Float64}, ::Int64, ::Function, ::Plots.Font) at gr.jl:412
(::Plots.#kw##gr_set_font)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Plots.#gr_set_font, ::Plots.Font) at <missing>:0
gr_set_xticks_font(::Plots.Subplot{Plots.GRBackend}) at gr.jl:605
_update_min_padding!(::Plots.Subplot{Plots.GRBackend}) at gr.jl:654
_collect(::Array{RecipesBase.AbstractLayout,2}, ::Base.Generator{Array{RecipesBase.AbstractLayout,2},Plots.#_update_min_padding!}, ::Base.EltypeUnknown, ::Base.HasShape) at array.jl:488
_update_min_padding!(::Plots.GridLayout) at layouts.jl:310
_collect(::Array{RecipesBase.AbstractLayout,2}, ::Base.Generator{Array{RecipesBase.AbstractLayout,2},Plots.#_update_min_padding!}, ::Base.EltypeUnknown, ::Base.HasShape) at array.jl:488
_update_min_padding!(::Plots.GridLayout) at layouts.jl:310
prepare_output(::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}) at plot.jl:262
show(::IOStream, ::MIME{Symbol("application/pdf")}, ::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}) at output.jl:209
pdf(::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}, ::String) at output.jl:25
savefig(::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}, ::String) at output.jl:123
BEST_MAIN() at MAIN_BEST.jl:252
include_string(::String, ::String) at loading.jl:522
include_string(::Module, ::String, ::String) at Compat.jl:174
(::Atom.##57#60{String,String})() at eval.jl:74
withpath(::Atom.##57#60{String,String}, ::String) at utils.jl:30
withpath(::Function, ::String) at eval.jl:38
macro expansion at eval.jl:72 [inlined]
(::Atom.##56#59{Dict{String,Any}})() at task.jl:80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, there is a bug with the GR backend which in roots related to  "@eval import #backend" in the Plots code, as described [here](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/1047).
The workaround for now would be to use an additional line importing the backend, in your case GR, after using command for the Plots module, something similar to the code below:

```html
using Plots
import GR

#your code here
```